# Getting error while running opencv code in C

Tags: c, opencv

I am having a opencv code in C:

```
#ifdef _CH_
#pragma package <opencv>
#endif

  #ifndef _EiC
    // motion templates sample code
 #include "cv.h"
   #include "highgui.h"
 #include <time.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#endif
```

with these header files.

if I run it using

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` motempl_temp.c -o opencv
```

I get error:

```
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvDecRefData':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xac2): undefined reference to `cvFree_'
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xb4b): undefined reference to `cvFree_'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvGetRow':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xc63): undefined reference to `cvGetRows'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvGetCol':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xc91): undefined reference to `cvGetCols'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvReleaseMatND':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xcab): undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvSubS':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xe08): undefined reference to `cvAddS'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvCloneSeq':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xe5a): undefined reference to `cvSeqSlice'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvSetNew':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xed6): undefined reference to `cvSetAdd'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvGetSetElem':
 motempl_temp.c:(.text+0xf93): undefined reference to `cvGetSeqElem'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvEllipseBox':
motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x1062): undefined reference to `cvEllipse'
/tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvFont':
 motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x10ce): undefined reference to `cvInitFont'
    /tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvReadIntByName':
 motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x11d8): undefined reference to 
  `cvGetFileNodeByName'
 /tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvReadRealByName':
  motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x1277): undefined reference to 
  `cvGetFileNodeByName'
 /tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvReadStringByName':
 motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x1306): undefined reference to 
 `cvGetFileNodeByName'
 /tmp/cc2rKXbX.o: In function `cvReadByName':
  motempl_temp.c:(.text+0x1349): undefined reference to 
 `cvGetFileNodeByName'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All the header files are in the path `/usr/local/include/opencv` folder and this is included in the path variable.

Comment: @zindarod that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenCV C API is deprecated](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/?answer=17820#post-id-17820). You should use the C++ API.

You can compile your code with `g++`:

```
g++ motempl_temp.c -o opencv `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

Comment: The problem is not that `g++`  should have been preferred to `gcc`, the problem was coming from the `pkg-config ...` was coming before the `.c` file.

Comment: @purplepsycho Yes, that's right. But I wanted to point out that the C API is not maintained anymore, so even if OP had used `pkg-config` properly, there'd still have been undefined errors in compiling code with `gcc`.